# Correr un archivo.py que exporta un png (un plot) desde Java

Tags: java, python, script, matplotlib

Tengo un algoritmo escrito en Python, que al ejecutarlo exporta a una ruta un PNG (realmente es un plot) y para ello hace uso de las librerías de Matplotlib y Seaborn, este es:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import datetime
import seaborn as sns
from openpyxl import load_workbook
sns.set(color_codes=True)

# # MÁS CÓDIGO AQUÍ SOBRE LEER DATOS DE UN EXCELL

def Statistics():
    x = [2*i for i in range(10)]
    y = [i for i in range(10)]

    sns.set()

    plt.xticks(x , y)
    plt.scatter(x, y ,color = 'darkred')
    plt.bar(x, y)

    plt.show()

    plt.savefig('C:/carpeta 1/carpeta 2 ... /plot.png') 
    # Quiero que sea una carpeta que requiera privilegios de administrador

Statistics()
```

Pero mi problema es que al correr el script en java, como se indica a continuación simplemente no ocurre nada:

```java
public class PythonCaller {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Preparando las variables para la ejecución
        String pythonScriptPath = "C:/carpeta 1/carpeta 2 ... /miScript.py";
        String[] cmd = new String[2];
        cmd[0] = "C:\\miPath\\a mi versión de\\python.exe"; // My version de Python 3.8
        cmd[1] = pythonScriptPath;

        // Ejecutando
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);
        // A mi me da igual el ouput, lo que quierro es que corra el código y que genere el png
        // Esta parte de abajo que recibe lo compilado en el script, es para un experimento a continuación

        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
        // Imprimir el contenido compilado
                System.out.println(line);   }
      }
}
```

Sin embargo, sí funciona con el siguiente script de Python:

```py
def miniTest():
    print ("HELLO WORLD HERE")

miniTest()
```

Y en la consola del IDE (estoy usando NetBeans) me imprime `HELLO WORLD`

¿Alguna forma de correr  desde java esta app escrita en Python?

Comment: Hola Nassif. ¿que significa la siguiente expresioń?  "C:/carpeta 1/carpeta 2 ... /miScript.py"

Comment: Estas mezclando "\" y "/" en los paths ...

Comment: @Alvaro C Eso es la ruta dondea donde se exportará el png

Comment: @Candid Moe eso no es ningún problema, en mismo programa en Java puedes tener dos rutas en una empleando el \\ y en otra / siempre y cuando no los mezcles en la misma ruta. Lo que no es relevante. Tampoco se uede hacer uso \ sin usarlo como \\ porque Java lo interpreta comp caracter especial

Comment: Nassif. La ruta de la imagen corresponde a la logica del programa python no tiene que ver con la invocación del programa desde Java.

Comment: @Alvaro C. Sí lo sé, pero simplemente indico que se va a exportar a una carpeta (que existe) y listo no pretendo nada más con ese dato

Comment: Ya lo he resuelto. El problema era que tenía que incluir la instalación de las librerías de python que vaya a necesitar por```pip install```. Yo tenia las librerías de python y Python en sí instalados por el administrador Anaconda, que por lo visto no es lo valido para hacer esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre Fedora y usando paths completos como en el ejemplo de código mostrado:

```
public class PythonCaller {
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        System.out.println("Invocando al python");
        // Preparando las variables para la ejecución
        String pythonScriptPath = "/home/alvaro/programacion/python/lejano/miScrip.py";
        String[] cmd = new String[2];
        cmd[0] = "/usr/bin/python"; // Mi version de Python 3.8
        cmd[1] = pythonScriptPath;

        // Ejecutando
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process pr = rt.exec(cmd);
        // A mi me da igual el ouput, lo que quierro es que corra el código y que genere el png
        // Esta parte de abajo que recibe lo compilado en el script, es para un experimento a continuación

        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
        // Imprimir el contenido compilado
                System.out.println(line);   }
      }
}
```

Esto genera la salida (comente la linea que hace ptl.savefig ):

[image: En ejecución]

Ahora bien, si en el Sistema Operativo donde se ejecuta están todas las librerías necesarias para que se ejecute el programa desde Python entonces invocarlo desde otro lenguaje no debe dar problemas.

Cada programa debe encapsular su lógica para favorecer el desacoplamiento.

Coloco la respuesta por si alguien tiene interes en ver como se haría una llamada a un programa Python desde Java. Unicamente agregar que es mejor usar commons-exec (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/changes-report.html) y no Runtime pues presenta una mejor manera más limpia y legible de hacer invocaciones.